# Turtle: how to read a list of files?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Assume we have a file `my_file.txt` with contents:

```
foo
bar
```

and another file `my_other_file.txt` containing:

```
baz
```

I would like to read the contents of these two files using [`turtle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.4) so that I get a [`Shell`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.4/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#t:Shell) of lines which will produce:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

In Haskell's `turtle` library one can read a list of files by using [`input`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.4/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:input), for instance:

```
view $ input "my_file.txt"
```

We have that

```
input :: FilePath -> Shell Line
```

And `Shell` has no `Monoid` instances (which I think makes sense since we cannot associate `IO` operations), so the only operator I can think of using is [`(<|>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-):

```
view $ foldl (<|>) empty $ map input ["my_file.txt", "my_other_file.txt"]
```

While this produces the desired effect, I wonder whether there is a library in the `turtle` eco-system that takes care of this, or whether there is a `traverse` like operation that can be use on `Alternative`'s.

*EDIT*: the effect above could be also achieved by using [`asum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum):

```
asum $ input <$> ["my_file.txt", "my_other_file.txt"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Line` has a `Monoid` instance. If we have a list of `Line`s, we can [`mconcat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat) them into a single one:

```
do
  exampleA <- input "my_file.txt"
  exampleB <- input "my_other_file.txt"
  return $ mconcat [exampleA, exampleB]
```

Since `Shell` has an `Applicative` instance, we can use `traverse` to use `input` over a list of files:

```
traverse input ["my_file.txt","my_other_file.txt"]
```

We end up with a `Shell [Line]`. Since `Shell` is a `Functor`, we can `fmap` `mconcat` (or [`fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold) if you don't use a list):

```
mconcat <$> traverse input ["my_file.txt","my_other_file.txt"]
```

Comment: I've tried that but it does not seems to work. `view $  traverse input ["my_file.txt","my_other_file.txt"]` yields `[Line "foo",Line "baz"]
[Line "bar",Line "baz"]`, so the overall result when applying `mconcat` will be `Line "foobaz"
Line "barbaz"`. Or am I missing something?